# From PHP (LAMP) to Classic ASP, how to setup a dev environment

Tags: iis, macos, asp-classic, development-environment

I'm jumping into updating a Classic ASP web app coming from a PHP background and am trying to get my bearings. I'm used to just installing something like [MAMP](http://mamp.info), messing the httpd.conf a bit and getting on my way.

Ideally, I would like to be able to edit this app completely locally on my **Macbook Pro** running **OS X Leopard** so that I'm not messing with my client's server too much. Now, if I need to I'm willing to install Windows 7 via Boot Camp or running it as a virtual machine. Of course my preference is to stay completely in OS X, but I have my doubts about that possibility. So, how should I go about this?

One thing to note is that once I'm done updating this ASP web app I will have to make changes to a VB(.NET) application as well, so I'd like to have to change my virtual workspace as little as possible when that time comes around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you will need to install Windows via Boot Camp or VM (your choice).

Once in Windows, you can install Visual Studio 2010 (Express free), where you can edit your ASP Classic files, and you will have it already installed when you need to do VB.net

Do not forget to install IIS when you install Windows (you will need it to run ASP Classic)